# How to detect taps on a button whilst a delay caused by postDelayed Handler

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, timedelay, postdelayed

I want to solve a problem that I have been trying to do so the last couple of days but I don't have that much experience and I couldn't find the solution anywhere else.

Anyway, in my app I have a button in which I have implemented the onClickClistener in order to respond to touch and inside that I have added a Handler which adds a delay and after that some code is being executed. My problem is that I want to detect any tap of the button whilst the delay is happening and the postDelayed function doesn't allow me to do so. How can I actually do that?
I've posted my code that is related on that.
Thanks in advance!

P.S(I don't mind not using this postDelayed thing.)

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            .......
            
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  
                //Do some thing after the delay
                
               }
            }, randomDelay);
            
            //Do other things
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean previousTapDetected;
...
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            .......
            if(previousTapDetected) {
                //We got a tap during the delay
            }
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            previousTapDetected = true;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    previousTapDetected = false;
                //Do some thing after the delay

               }
            }, randomDelay);

            //Do other things
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, but how can i stop everything when for example it detects a tap during the delay? I cant figure it out.

Comment: Actually never mind I made a mistake which caused a part of the code to repeat again and again